# Netbeans issues with tomcat context.xml

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, netbeans, jndi

I have the following JNDI realm ldap "thing" that used to reside inside of `META-INF/context.xml`

```
 // Obviously i changed some of the code here to hide certain key information
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" 
     connectionName="uid=admin,ou=system" 
     connectionPassword="<PASSWORD>" 
     debug="99" 
     roleBase="<ROLEBASE>"
     roleName="cn" roleNested="true" 
     roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})" 
     roleSubtree="true" 
     userBase="USERBASE" 
     userSearch="(mail={0})"
     connectionURL="ldap://MACHINE:10389"
```

/>

Now that I'm nearing a production phase of my work I wanted to move this file into the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` file instead so that I can do a machine based configuration.  I did this on two linux boxes no problem, however, when I do it on my development machine and try to run (in netbeans) i get this prompt

[image]

Is there something key I'm missing here?  Even if i type in the correct password netbeans gets into a strange loop and won't take the password.  As soon as i remove the Realm def everything works fine.

Am I doing something terribly wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue as well and I was able to fix this by pasting the UserDatabaseRealm from `server.xml`:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                   resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

into the tomcat manager webapp `context.xml`

```
webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml
```

and also the `manager.xml` that is found in the folder at:

```
%APPDATA%\NetBeans\<netbeans version>\apache-tomcat-<version>_base\conf\Catlina\localhost
```

I believe you only really need to paste it into the `%APPDATA%\NetBeans\<netbeans version>\apache-tomcat-<version>_base\conf\Catlina\localhost\manager.xml` folder but it doesn't hurt to put it in both to be safe.

For reference, this is what my `manager.xml` file looks like now and everything is working as expected again:

```
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager" antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
</Context>
```

Hopefully this works for you as well!  It was a pretty annoying issue that I scratched my head about for around an hour.

EDIT: Note: Of course, the location of your `conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml` file is probably different and may not be in your AppData\Roaming folder.  To get the actual location you can grab it from the server properties in Tomcat.  Go to Tools > Servers and look for the path listed in `Catalina Base:`